# 'undefined' has no propType for native prop error react native

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get up and running with react native.
I have xcode and watchmen installed as required in this link.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Following the quickstart I have done the below

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

`react-native init AwesomeProject`

`In the newly created folder AwesomeProject/`

`Open AwesomeProject.xcodeproj and hit run in Xcode.`

When I do this I get the 'red error screen' in my iphone emulator with the below message.

`'undefined' has no propType for native prop 'RCTMap.mapType' of native type 'MKMapType'`

I have had a look at the [troubleshooting link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html#content) but have not been able to identify this as a known error.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Seems like you're using the MapView but you don't show that in your question.

Comment: Thanks @ColinRamsay so far I have simply run the react-native init command.  I will look through the files generated to see if I can see more information relating to MapView and update the question

Comment: Found this bug with several suggestions:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1812

Comment: thanks @ColinRamsay I ended up updating to xcode 6.4 which reset my computer and the packager which fixed the problem as suggested in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens when the xcode packager stops working correctly. How I fix it:

1. Stop xcode
2. Close the terminal running packager
3. Clean solution
4. Click Build and Run (play button)